# Flutter new web project not showing in Visual Studio command palette

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual Studio Code, Dart and Flutter correctly according to the tutorial step shown in docs. I have checked it 100 times but nothing is wrong, unable to find issue.

Expected result in Flutter:

New web project must be visible in in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Update your visual studio code to latest version (Version 1.35.0 (1.35.0) OR Above) and install Flutter and Dart plugin again

Comment: I already have latest version, I ended up using Android Studio, actually it's easier since we can add web compatibility to a flutter app project.

Answer (score 18):

I was not able to get 'Flutter: New Web Project", but following https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web from the Flutter Docs got me running the app on the web. Hope it helps. Below are the commands that I entered in Visual Studio Code's terminal

```
$ flutter channel dev
$ flutter upgrade
$ flutter config --enable-web
$ mkdir <new_project_directory_name>
$ cd <into new_project_directory>
$ flutter create .
$ flutter run -d chrome
```

Comment: I was a bit confused at first by this approach but after implementation I kind of understood the code much better. Worked perfectly - only solution I found.

Answer (score 3):

Flutter: New Web Project [was removed](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/pull/2005) from the VS Code extension.  The excuse was this was always supposed to be temporary and it broke with the latest release of 'Stagehand'.  But removing it makes it harder to create a new web project.  I followed the directions given in answer by @ALotLikeEss.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it's working for me :

open `terminal` in project folder and execute this :

```
flutter config --enable-web
```

And restart your IDE

Answer (score 0):

Run commando in terminal `flutter config --enable-web`, restart your vscode or android studio and try again..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. if flutter plugin is installed, direct visual studio code to a folder (open a folder) then select  view>command palette> or press ctrl+shift+p short cut keys, then write flutter. Flutter:New Project item will be displayed. Opening a folder solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons I was confused between the **search bar** and the **command palette**, the later which is not docked onto the interface

For me, the search bar will not find any flutter command, while the command palette, which will popup on top of the search bar and have your command prefixed by '>' will work.

Answer (score -1):

Simply select "Debug" and "Start Debugging" from the menu. After this, the command palette will appear.

[image: Start debugging]

Comment: This did not fix anything for me.

Answer (score -2):

Update your visual studio code to latest version (Version 1.35.0 (1.35.0)) and install Flutter and Dart plugin

Comment: @ManishPatel i got update my vscode to latest but still it's not showing for web

Comment: Above Solution is only for Flutter Version less then 9