# VS Code "Flutter: New Web Project" doest not show

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I just downloaded latest version of VS Code and setup all the required packages for VS Code. and try to create my first web app not I can't able to found **`Flutter: New Web Project`**.
Any one get same issue ? How can create new flutter web app?

I only see:

[image]

**VS Code:**

```
Version: 1.41.1
```

> **~ PS** : I am following https://itnext.io/flutter-for-web-c75011a41956 and https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-started-with-flutter-web-e187829c9dd3 tutorials. And I can done Flutter Web by android studio.

Comment: Have you tried this guide https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Comment: I have done at my end

Answer (score 2):

From the [Flutter web documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web), you'll want to run the following commands in the terminal to enable web support:

```
 flutter channel beta
 flutter upgrade
 flutter config --enable-web
```

Flutter for web is still in beta, so you need to complete these few extra steps to get it working. VSCode should allow you to create a Flutter web project after you've done this.

Answer (score 0):

1. first of all you have to install dart and flutter package into vs
   code.
2. then press ctrl + shift + p to create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Open up VS Code, and press Ctrl+Shift+P, and start typing flutter, we see that in the list of available actions for Flutter, there is an option that says, Flutter: New Web Project.

Comment: I already did all require setup for it. But can't see new web project

Comment: sorry I can't get you .. can you pls elaborate ?

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-create-and-deploy-a-website-from-scratch-4a026ebd6c

Comment: All the setup are done I can run flutter web by Android Studio by using terminal. I am following https://itnext.io/flutter-for-web-c75011a41956 and https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-started-with-flutter-web-e187829c9dd3

Comment: Any luck .. ? Can you do one thing ? can you pls update your VS Code 1.41.1 ? and check ?

Comment: No but i found this problem is still open in stackoverflow :  i think not only yu
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522065/flutter-new-web-project-not-showing-in-visual-studio-command-palette

Comment: Ok no worry pls inform here If you get any update .. anyways thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

**Flutter: New Web Project** is not available in VS Code.
Follow these steps given in the [Official Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab-web#:%7E:text=You%20only%20need%20to%20run,that%20it%27s%20in%20your%20path.&text=If%20you%20have%20problems%20enabling,Run%20flutter%20doctor%20.):

```
 $flutter channel stable
 $flutter upgrade
 $flutter config --enable-web
 $flutter create myapp
 $cd myapp
 $flutter run -d chrome   (required if multiple devices are connected)
```